# Composer requirements could not be resolved

Tags: composer-php

I'm trying to update my composer dependencies and composer can't resolve my requirements. I've tried updating rezzza/formulate and hoa/math, but I always get this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- rezzza/formulate v1.0.2 requires hoa/math dev-master -> satisfiable by hoa/math[dev-master].
- rezzza/formulate v1.0.2 requires hoa/math dev-master -> satisfiable by hoa/math[dev-master].
- Removal request for hoa/math == 9999999-dev
- Installation request for rezzza/formulate == 1.0.2.0 -> satisfiable by rezzza/formulate[v1.0.2].
```

Here is my Composer config:

```
"require": {
    "bernard/bernard": "~0.11",
    "bshaffer/oauth2-server-php": "v1.5",
    "doctrine/annotations": "~1.1",
    "doctrine/cache": "~1.3",
    "doctrine/collections": "v1.1",
    "goodby/csv": "dev-master",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "~3.7",
    "herrera-io/date-interval": "~1.0",
    "jms/serializer": "~0.13",
    "kriswallsmith/buzz": "0.12",
    "lexpress/doctrine1": "1.3.0",
    "lexpress/symfony1": "1.5.3",
    "merk/dough": "~1.1.4",
    "misd/guzzle-bundle": "~1.0",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.7.0",
    "namshi/notificator": "~1.0",
    "parse/php-sdk": "~1.0.4",
    "predis/predis": "dev-master",
    "raven/raven": "~0.7.0",
    "rezzza/formulate": "~1.0",
    "symfony/console": "~2.4",
    "symfony/security": "~2.5",
    "symfony/templating": "~2.4",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.4",
    "symfony/validator": "~2.4",
    "twig/twig": "1.*",
    "willdurand/hateoas": "~2.1",
    "willdurand/negotiation": "~1.2",
    "yohang/finite": "~1.0",
    "yzalis/ua-parser": "dev-browserscope-yml-support"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*"
},
"prefer-stable": true,
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    }
}
```

It seems that the removal request is what's tripping me up, but I'm not even sure what that means. I also see two different version formats for the `rezzza/formulate` library: 1.0.2 and 1.0.2.0 -- maybe that's also an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ran `composer update rezzza/formulate`, which solved my installation requirements problem.